# What is the number of columns of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that:

$$Ax = (2,4,2)^T$$

and a complete solution is $$x=(2,0,0)^T+c(1,1,0)^T+d(0,0,1)^T$$

How do I know that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix? Obviously, A has $3$ rows, we also know that the null space is $2$ dimensional. But I cannot use this information to obtain the number of columns of $A$:

$$\dim N(A) + C(A^T) = n$$
and
$$\dim N(A^T)+C(A) = m$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, then in the equation $Ax = b$: $b$ must be a vector on $m$ entries, and $x$ must be a vector on $n$ entries.  We may thereby infer from the equation and given solution that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix (that is, both $m$ and $n$ are $3$).

Comment: $Ax $ is $m \times n$ matrix multiplied by $n \times 1$ vector. Therefore the product is an $m \ \times 1$ vector, irrespective of $n $. Clearly, my reasoning must be wrong somewhere

Comment: In order for the product to be defined, the $n$ from the matrix has to match the $n$ from the vector $x$.  Hence, if $x$ is $3 \times 1$ and $Ax$ is a well defined multiplication, $A$ must have $3$ columns.

Comment: I must be missing something very obvious. If $x$ is $2 \times 1$ then we will still have a product that is $3 \times 1$... And that would mean that $A$ has $2$ columns

Comment: You know what the solution for $x$ is. (It was the second equation in the question.) It is $3\times1$.

Comment: Oh dear... It would be more straightforward to answer this question by precisely saying that. That we know that $x$ is $3 \times 1$.. and since that is the case then $n=3$. Thanks

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal I'm not a mind reader; I didn't know what exactly you were missing.  Glad it makes sense to you now, though.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for the answer